# Error in in codebuild while executing if else condition inside for loop

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, jq, aws-codebuild

Below is my buildspec.yaml file to list the images inside ecr and I'm using to for loop and if elese condition to find a particular imageId exists or not

```
version: 0.2

phases:

  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - echo test
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)

  build:
    commands:
      - aws ecr list-images --repository-name mytestecrrepo > ecr.json
      - cat ecr.json
      - for imageTag in $(jq -r '.imageIds[].imageTag' < ecr.json); do 
        if [ $imageTag = "1.0" ]; then 
        echo "value exists" 
        else 
        echo "value doesntexists" 
        fi 
        done
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

For some reason, code build is throwing the below error

**/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

I'm doing something wrong within the shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following in your `build`:

```
  build:
    commands:
      - aws ecr list-images --repository-name mytestecrrepo > ecr.json
      - cat ecr.json
      - |
        for imageTag in $(jq -r '.imageIds[].imageTag' < ecr.json); do 
        if [ $imageTag = "1.0" ]; then 
        echo "value exists" 
        else 
        echo "value doesntexists" 
        fi 
        done
```